# Cannot update in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: command-line, 12.10, internet, software-sources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

I tried to update, going to the dash, go to software update and wait for it to tell me to update. But it appears that it failed to download the information from the repository. check connection to the internet (which works fine). If someone tells me how to fix the problem, or how to upgrade from console, I would appreciate it.

PS:  This is part of what appears in details:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/mobile/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/mobile/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably something is wrong with your `/etc/apt/sources.list` document. You should remove your PPAs, because it seems that someting is wrong with them. Open a terminal (Strg + Alt + T) and type `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`. After you've entered your password, you can see all the PPAs and official repositorys.
The standard sources.list file looks like this:

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

So, delete all the entries and paste the repositorys above into the file. Then press Strg + O for saving changes and than Strg + X for exiting.

*Please remark, that all your manually added PPAs are deleted in this way. But you can add them later again, if you have updated your programs.*